# How to set up a UIViewController with a tableView in it

Tags: swift

I have a View Controller with a table view in it. However, when I attempt to add both `UIViewController` and `UITableViewController` on my class' header, I get an error. It only compiles and runs when I solely add `UITableViewController` but then freezes and gives a "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" error.

Adding `UITableViewDelegate` does not work as well.

Comment: `UITableViewController` inheirts from `UIViewController`. So you only need to declare that you subclass `UITableViewController` and you will get both.

Comment: @keithbhunter Thank you, how do I do that?

Comment: `class DriverViewController: UITableViewController`

Comment: This is what I said in the question. When I do this, it compiles and runs, but gives me a "Thread 1: signal SIGABRT" error afterwards.

Comment: Can you post the full code? The exact line `class DriverViewController: UITableViewController` should never crash. You must have something else going on.

Comment: I just added the code in the question space.

Comment: What line, specifically, gives the SIGABRT error?

Answer (score 0):

To have a UITableView in your regular UIViewController you need to place a TableView in your storyboard UIViewController, make a reference to in your view controller .m and add UITableViewConrtoller delegate:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UITableViewDelegate_Protocol/

Alternatively, you can just use a UITableViewController.

Comment: Thank you. I'm new at coding and I do so in Swift, I don't have .m and .h classes. So how do I go about that in Swift?

Comment: Just use yourViewController.swift class

Comment: Thank you again, I just tried to apply this and I get, "Cannot override a stored property"

Comment: Well, I need more context to be able to help

Comment: in your code I don't see a reference to a tableView? neither a tableViewDelegate setup.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing 'class DriverViewController: UITableViewController' to 'class DriverViewController: UIViewController' and add 'UITableViewDataSource' and 'UITableViewDelegate'. In viewDidLoad, you have to call 'self.yourTableView.dataSource = self' and 'self.yourTableView.delegate = self'

Comment: Thank you very much Dan! Most of your solution works, but I get a new error this time, which is:
http://imgur.com/K3B4RS4

Comment: It's on the link below. It says "Redundant conformance of 'DriverViewController' to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource' " and "Redundant conformance of 'DriverViewController' to protocol 'UITableViewDataSource' "

Comment: Try getting rid of the 'UITableViewDataSource' and 'UITableViewDelegate' at the top and see what happens

Comment: It compiles, but then I still get redirected to the app delegate's first line with the SIGABRT error.

Comment: Ok. It sounds like something went wrong along the way. If your ViewController in the storyboard says it is a UITableViewController, your swift file must say "class DriverViewController: UITableViewController". If it says UIViewController, your Swift file must say "class DriverViewController: UIViewController" and you have to conform to those protocols --  'UITableViewDataSource' and 'UITableViewDelegate'. You can check what your ViewController is my clicking on the yellow circle and go into the Identity Inspector. Delete what is in the class textField and see what it says.

Comment: If it is a UIViewController, you have to set up the tableView's dataSource and Delegate.

Comment: Thank you. So it's a UIViewController and I set up the tableView's dataSource and delegate, but whenever I declare the class is a UIViewController in the header, I get more errors and it does not compile at all. What I have is a UIViewController with a tableView in it.

Comment: Did you connect the delegate and dataSource using control + click from the table view up to the yellow circle?

Comment: Yes I did it that way.

Comment: At this point, I would say re-do it. I'm assuming you are following a tutorial. Or you could put your project on GitHub or Dropbox and send the link to me

Comment: I think UIVIewController is required in the header, along with UITableViewController because I have a left side navigation bar.